# The instruction (Keys.ARROW_DOWN) is moving the cursor to the bottom of the dropdown list instead of the first option

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**Scenario:** To search and select the first destination location that matches the input string using the below code.

**Code snippet:**

driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://www.emirates.com/nz");

Thread.sleep(2000L);;

WebElement Depfield =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'active')]//*[@name='Departure airport']"));

Depfield.click();

Depfield.sendKeys("lag");

Thread.sleep(2000L);;

Depfield.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);

Depfield.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}

**Issue:** The instruction Depfield.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) is actually moving the cursor to the bottom of the search drop down list instead of the first matched option. As a result, no option is being selected by the following instruction - Depfield.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN). 
I have tried with for loop to go one option after the other but it didn't work.

[image]

New Update: New result

[image]

**Request:**
Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: it works for me ,it selecting Lagos nigeria

Comment: Hi Friend. Thank you for the response. I have run the code multiple times but it never selected Lagos Nigeria. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my latest results.

Comment: sorry my mistake, ya you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works:

```
         Depfield.sendKeys("lag");

         Thread.sleep(2000L);;

         Depfield.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.RETURN);
```

I think the keypress is not released until another keypress is provided, so for clicking second element use:

```
Depfield.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.RETURN);
```

You can use actions class also:

```
       Depfield.sendKeys("lag");

         Thread.sleep(2000L);;

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action drawAction = builder.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
                  .build();
        drawAction.perform();
```

Comment: You are a genius, my friend! It has worked now with your code. What a big sigh of relief. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. Sure, I will try with actions class too.

Comment: Could you upvote also, by clicking the up arrow near to my answer

Comment: May I ask you to explain in detail (if possible) why my code didn't work? Am I not supposed to use the keys like that?

Comment: As i mentioned, I think the keypress is not released until another keypress is provided, I saw the focus going all the way to the end of the drop-down. I am not much sure

Comment: No problem friend. I have upvoted this answer and yesterday's answer too.